# How to check if a MySQL result is empty

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
    // Populate headers
    $fields = $result->fetch_fields();
    foreach ($fields as $field)
        printf("<th>%s</th>", $field->name);

    printf("</tr>");

    // Write to table
    while ($myvar = $result->fetch_row()) {

        $date = $myvar[0];
        $room_ID = $myvar[1];
        $description = $myvar[2];
        $firstname = $myvar[3];
        $lastname = $myvar[4];
        $message = $myvar[5];
        $period = $myvar[6];

        printf("<tr>");
        printf("<td>%s</td><td>%s</td>", $date, $room_ID);
        printf("<td>%s</td><td>%s</td>", $description, $firstname);
        printf("<td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td>", $lastname, $message, $period);
        printf("</tr>");

  }
```

I'm trying to echo "No results to display" if my MySQLi result returns empty. The problem is the headers are returned as part of the array, how can I achieve this?

Comment: `num_rows()` would help. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check with number of rows. if it return zero it means table contain no rows. try below code.

```
// Populate headers
    $fields = $result->fetch_fields();
    foreach ($fields as $field)
        printf("<th>%s</th>", $field->name);

    printf("</tr>");

    // Write to table
    if($result->num_rows== 0){
     echo "No Result to display";
    }else{
    while ($myvar = $result->fetch_row()) {

        $date = $myvar[0];
        $room_ID = $myvar[1];
        $description = $myvar[2];
        $firstname = $myvar[3];
        $lastname = $myvar[4];
        $message = $myvar[5];
        $period = $myvar[6];

        printf("<tr>");
        printf("<td>%s</td><td>%s</td>", $date, $room_ID);
        printf("<td>%s</td><td>%s</td>", $description, $firstname);
        printf("<td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td>", $lastname, $message, $period);
        printf("</tr>");

  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`num_rows`** to get the total value of records retrieved from the query.

```
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
if($row_cnt>0){ echo "Have data";}else{echo "No data";}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple use num_rows**

```
  if($result->num_rows== 0){
 echo "no results to display"
  }
else{
  while ($myvar = $result->fetch_row()) {
  //Your Code here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `num_rows` to get the total value of records.

```
$row_count = $result->num_rows;
if($row_count>0)
{ 
    echo "Data Available";
}
else
{
    echo "No Data Available";
}
```